# Anagrams finding in java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I stuck on a problem. I have a String array which is consist of `String[]={"eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"}` Now, I should segregated those word which have same letter on it and make a group. `eat,tea,ate` they have same letter in each word so this is a group. Group 2 should be `tan,nat` and Group3 should be `bat`. So I have to make a list of list to store those groups.

**My approach:**

To solve this problem I first find out the ascii values of each letter and then add those ascii values for a word. Like `eat` find out the ascii values of `e,a,t` and add them. I take this approach because if the letters are repeated in the words then they must have same ascii sum. After that I group them same Ascii sums and find out which words have those sums then they belongs to same group.

**My progress** 
I find out  ascii sums and put them in a hashmap. But then I could not  group the same values. As I failed to group the ascii values I cannot find out the words.I have no clue how to proceed.

I also follow this posts

[post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834128/c-finding-anagrams-in-words)
[post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821779/finding-anagram-using-hashmap)

But there approach and my approach is not same. Also the questions are different from mine. I am discussing here about a different approach which is depend upon ASCII values.

**My code:**

```
public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {
    ArrayList<Character>indivistr=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer>dup=new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<Integer,Integer>mappingvalues=new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0;i<strs.length;i++){
        int len=strs[i].length();
        int sum=0;
        for(int j=0;j<len;j++){
            indivistr.add(strs[i].charAt(j));
            int ascii=(int)strs[i].charAt(j);
            sum=sum+ascii;

        }
        mappingvalues.put(i,sum);

    }
```

}

*One more approach*
I transfer the map keys in a Arraylist and map values in a ArrayList. Something like that,

`ArrayList<Integer>key_con=new ArrayList<
(mappingvalues.keySet());
 ArrayList<Integer>val_con=new ArrayList<>(mappingvalues.values());`

Then using two loops and put the same values into another list.

```
for(int k=0;k<val_con.size();k++){
        for(int k1=k+1;k1<val_con.size();k1++){
            if(val_con.get(k).equals(val_con.get(k1))){
                dup.add(val_con.get(k1));
            }
        }
```

Now if I print dup output will be `[314, 314, 314, 323]` which is partially correct. It should be `314,314,314,323,323,311`

Comment: "A healthy discussion always welcome." <-- No, this isn't a chat site.  It's a question and answer site.  And I'm struggling to see a question here.

Comment: have you tried to use an additional variable. So you put the initial word to that variable. Now iterate over all the words. For every word, for every letter you examine if it is in your saved word - if you get a  miss continue.  (If letters may occur multiple times in one word you may need some counter per letter)

Comment: Related (and honestly I'm tempted to consider it a dupe:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/15045640/1079354)

Comment: @JoeC Sometime I observed that when someone question here . He or she got answer like that **We don't solve home works**. So , I think, write down a whole code may be out of rules. So I encouraged a discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the asci approach I have made a working code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] values ={"eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"};
        Map<Integer, List<String>> resultMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
        for (String value : values) {
            char[] caharacters = value.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
            int asciSum = 0;
            for (char character : caharacters) {
                asciSum = asciSum + (int)character;
            }
            System.out.println(asciSum);
            if(resultMap.containsKey(asciSum)) {
                resultMap.get(asciSum).add(value);
            }else {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add(value);
                resultMap.put(asciSum, list);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(resultMap);
    }
```

This will give result

```
{323=[tan, nat], 311=[bat], 314=[eat, tea, ate]}
```

but if we encounter diff characters with same asci value sum like 10+11 = 20+1
below code will work where based on the sorted string we make the result map

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] values ={"eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"};
        Map<String, List<String>> resultMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        for (String value : values) {
            char[] caharacters = value.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(caharacters);
            String sortedValue = new String(caharacters);
            System.out.println(sortedValue);
            if(resultMap.containsKey(sortedValue)) {
                resultMap.get(sortedValue).add(value);
            }else {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add(value);
                resultMap.put(sortedValue, list);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(resultMap);
    }
```

This will return

```
{aet=[eat, tea, ate], abt=[bat], ant=[tan, nat]}
```

I have fixed the comments and edits provided.

Comment: the aproach with some is wrong, you won't get correct result from some inputs. If you get a sum of 200, how do you now it was made my adding 100 + 100, or by adding 90 + 110 ?

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String[] words ={"eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"};

        for(List<String> list : groupAnagrams(words))
            System.out.println(list);

    }

    public static List<ArrayList<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] words) {

        List<ArrayList<String>> wordGroups = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();

        for(String word : words) {

            int sum = 0;
            for(char c : word.toCharArray())
                sum += c;
            if(map.containsKey(sum))
                map.get(sum).add(word);
            else {
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add(word);
                map.put(sum, list);
            }

        }

        for(ArrayList<String> list : map.values())
            wordGroups.add(list);

        return wordGroups;
    }
}
```

This program will work for small scale things such as this but consider the following input data:

{"a", "@!"}

The sum of these Strings are both 97.

Since you're using ASCII values to find anagrams you might run into a case such as this. This isn't a particularly pressing matter until you start messing around with lowercase letters and capitals. Easy fix for that is just a `String.ToUpperCase()` and map the symbols to huge numbers and you're good to go.

Comment: It had given that all words in lower case.

Comment: @Encipher absolutely. I created an ArrayList of ArrayLists for the groups to be stored in. I then created a HashMap that took an Integer (the sum of the string) as the key and an ArrayList of String which was the group. I then looped through all words in my String array and added up each character into a sum variable. I then checked if my HashMap already contained the sum. If it did add it to the specified group. If not then create a new group with the key sum. I then added all the HashMap values to an ArrayList which is optional. If I need to elaborate more on a specific area let me know.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity:

```
public class anagrams {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int numberOfAnagrams = 0;
    String[] stringArray = {"eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat", "plate", "knot"};
    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(stringArray);

    for(int i = 0; i < stringList.size() - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < stringList.size(); j++) {
            if(isAnagram(stringList.get(i), stringList.get(j))) {
                System.out.println(stringList.get(i) + " " + stringList.get(j));
                numberOfAnagrams += 2;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(numberOfAnagrams);
}

private static boolean isAnagram(String s1, String s2) {
    // In order for two String to be anagrams, they must have the same length.
    if(s1.length() != s2.length()) {
        return false;
    }
    // If s2 does not contain even one of s1's chars return false.
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        if(!s2.contains("" + s1.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's my idea, first I would create a class that will store the original string and it's sorted version:

```
class Anagram {
   String s;
   String sorted;
}
```

Then I map the input to my list of `Anagram`:

```
List<Anagram> collect = Arrays.stream(strs)
            .map(a -> new Anagram(a, Arrays.stream(a.split(""))
                    .sorted()
                    .reduce(String::concat).get()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then I just group the obtained list by sorted string:

```
 Map<String, List<Anagram>> groupBy = collect
             .stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Anagram::getSorted));
```

Now you have the lists with grouped anagrams, just extract from them the original string:

```
List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

for(List<Anagram> list : collect1.values()) {
     List<String> myList = list.stream().map(Anagram::getS).collect(Collectors.toList());
     result.add(myList);
}
```